# A doubt regarding Newton's Laws of Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Here, in this case, the body starts with an initial velocity of zero. We can resolve its motion in two directions:

1. Displacement covered along H and
2. Displacement covered along L direction.

The time taken in case 1 is
$$T_1=\sqrt{\frac{2H}{g}}$$

The time taken in second case is
$$T_2=\sqrt{\frac{2L}{g\sin \theta}}$$

$T_1$=$T_2$ as 'time' is ("runs") the same for all dimensions. But it's not the case as they aren't equal. They become equal when we take $g\sin\theta$ as downward acceleration.

But why take it only in that way?

Comment: Why would you think that the acceleration component along the vertical direction is g? What does Newton's second laws says about acceleration and force? Is the weight the only force with a vertical component, acting on that block? Or by T1 you mean time taken if you just drop the block, freely and not along the incline? If this is the case, the two times don't have to be equal.

Comment: Error in the $sin\theta$ component. You misplaced it.

Comment: I mean that T¹ is only towards downward direction and T² along incline.

Comment: T1 is a time so it has no direction. What is the motion you associate with T1? Is the block in contact with the incline or is in free fall?

Answer (score 1):

Here, in this solution, I assume the wedge to be fixed to the ground.

First of all, what does these equations $$v=u+at\\ v^2 = u^2 + 2as\\s = ut + \frac 12 at^2$$ mean?

It means that a body, undergoing linear motion, has constant acceleration $a$ in the direction of velocity and that it's initial $u$ and time taken to gain to a velocity $v$, reach a distance $s$ is $t$.

Now tell me what your equation, $$T_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2H}g}$$ means. It means that the body is going down with an acceleration $g$, which if you observe, it actually is not. There is a component of normal reaction from the wedge that also acts along the vertical. Let $N$ be the normal force. So, net acceleration becomes $$\vec a = \frac{m\vec g-\vec N}m = \vec g-\frac{\vec N}m$$

Now, let's find out what is $N$. Since perpendicular to the surface of the wedge no force acts, $$ N = mg\cos\theta$$

Thus, the net acceleration becomes $$\left|\vec a\right| = g\sin\theta$$ along the inclined surface. And the vertical component of acceleration becomes $$a_{v} = a\sin\theta = g\sin^2\theta $$
Thus the "actual" $\,T_1$ ought to be $$T_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2H}{a_v}}=\sqrt{\frac{2H}{g\sin^2\theta}}$$

Also we know, $$L = \frac H{\sin\theta}$$ from which we get $$T_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2L}{g\sin\theta}} = T_2$$

Thus time becomes conserved. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

In spite of being true that in Newtonian mechanics all frames measure the same time intervals, the issue here could be conceptual: once you identify a reference frame, you follow the motion with the coordinates you have chosen and only then you can make the identifications with the textbook expressions. Let me clarify all these points, under the assumption that the wedge remains fixed.

1. Let $S'$ be an orthogonal reference frame at the top of the wedge, $+x'$ pointing to the ground. In this frame, the acceleration due to gravity decomposes as follows: $\vec{g} = (g\sin\theta,-g\cos\theta)$. From Newton's second law, it follows that
   \begin{align}
   \ddot{x'}& = g\sin\theta\\
   \ddot{y'}& = -g\cos\theta + N\ ,
   \end{align}
   where $N$ is the magnitude of the normal force exerted by the surface to the mass. Notice that in this frame, it is directed along the $+y'$ axis only. Since the initial conditions in this frame read $x'(0)=0$, $\dot{x'}(0)=0$, it follows from the first equation that at any time
   \begin{equation}
   x'(t) = \frac{1}{2}g\sin\theta\ t^{2}\ .
   \end{equation}
   The time to reach the ground is equivalent to set $x'=L$, that is
   \begin{equation}
   \boxed{t_{\text{fall}} = \sqrt{\frac{2L}{g\sin\theta}}}\ .
   \end{equation}
2. Regarding the equation for $y'$: under the assumption that at any time the box and the wedge remain in touch, it follows that $\ddot{y'}=0$ and the magnitude of $N$ is
   \begin{equation}
   \boxed{N = g\cos\theta}\ .
   \end{equation}
3. Now let us consider a frame $S$ with its origin on the corner where you drew the box of the right angle $\pi/2$, $+x$ oriented towards the symbol $\theta$. The equations of motion here are
   \begin{align}
   \ddot{x}& = N\sin\theta\\
   \ddot{y}& = N\cos\theta - g\ .
   \end{align}
   By plugging the magnitude of $N$, it follows that
   \begin{align}
   \ddot{y}& = g\cos^{2}\theta - g\\
   & = -g(1-\cos^{2}\theta)\\
   & = -g\sin^{2}\theta\ .
   \end{align}
   This differential equation is solvable: we know that $y(0)=H$, $\dot{y}(0)=0$. Thus,
   \begin{equation}
   y(t) = H - \frac{1}{2}g\sin^{2}\theta t^{2}\ .
   \end{equation}
   Clearly, the time to reach the ground is the time to reach $y=0$, i.e.
   \begin{equation}
   t_{\text{fall}} = \sqrt{\frac{2H}{g\sin^{2}\theta}}\ .
   \end{equation}
   But by trigonometry it is clear that $H = L\sin\theta$. Therefore,
   \begin{equation}
   \boxed{t_{\text{fall}} = \sqrt{\frac{2L}{g\sin\theta}}}\ ,
   \end{equation}
   which is the same expression we arrived to before.

Closing remarks:

A. The identification $s = a_{\text{constant}}t^{2}/2$ is valid if you have a constant acceleration and no initial conditions over $s, \dot{s}$.

B. You should be careful on defining a reference frame and all the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the force of gravity on the object, it applies a force on the ground on which it is placed which, in turn, due to Newton's third law, applies a force on it, perpendicular to the surface of contact. This force is termed normal force or normal reaction and is equal to mg if and only if the surface of contact is parallel to the surface of the Earth. In other words, when the object is placed on a horizontal surface. Now, as your surface isn't horizontal, the normal reaction will not be mg but will be mg into the cosine of the angle the incline makes with the normal. This gives you the value of net downward acceleration: g*sin(theta)